# EntityFramework is deleting my records on dbcontext creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core

In a .NET Core project I have the following model:

```
public class WrapperContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WrappedFunction> Functions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlite("Data Source=functions.db");
    }
}

public class WrappedFunction
{
    [Key]
    public int FunctionId { get; set; }
    public String FunctionName { get; set; }
    public String AssemblyPath { get; set; }
    public String FactoryName { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it is an Sqlite database.

I have added the initial migration and updated the database. Before running my test application I have populated the Functions table with a single record.  I can open the DB with SqliteManager to see the record is there.

I then try to access the DB with the following function:

```
    static MUinfo getInfoFor(String command)
    {
        UFInfo rv = null;

        using (var ctx = new WrapperContext())  // <---- record disappears here
        {
            foreach (var fn in ctx.Functions)
            {
                if (fn.FunctionName.Equals(command))
                {
                    rv = new UFInfo()
                    {
                        AssemblyPath = fn.AssemblyPath,
                        FactoryName = fn.FactoryName,
                        CommandName = command
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        if (rv != null) return rv;
        return "No Info for " + command;
    }
```

However, when stepping through the debugger I see that the `foreach` loop never executes as there are no records in the DB.  When I stop before executing the `foreach` I can verify (using SqliteManager) that my single record has been deleted from the database.

So, it would appear that the DbContext object is somehow deleting the data from the database.  Why would that be and what have I done wrong here?  I am fairly new to EntityFramework so I may have done something obvious, but it isn't obvious to me.

One additional bit of info here.  The project that does the db access is a library project.  I have to copy the DB over to the build directory of the application before populating it and running the application.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

**Edit 6/19/17 (18:51):**

OK.  A bit more information (thanks to @StevePy).  Nunit3 seems to conflict with EFCore (though I don't get any errors on restore) so I couldn't create a unit test for this.  So I inserted a `using (var ctx...)` above the one in the listing above and inserted a couple of dummy records.  Then I exited that using block and when I entered the one to traverse the records they were there.

However, I then commented out the dummy insertions and reran my test.  And, once again, **both** records disappeared.  So there is something very weird going on here with EFCore.

**Edit 6/20/17 (15:30):**
Well, I'm still not sure what is going on but there is an odd interaction between EFCore and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.

I decided to remove all references to EFCore and simply use SQL queries on the DB.  I did this without recreating the DB (so I was using the one already created by EFCore).  I noticed the exact same behavior when I created a new SqliteConnection without using EFCore.

In desperation I deleted the DB and recreated it from scratch using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.  This DB didn't have any of the EFCore information in it, obviously.  I then populated the DB with some test records and went to use it.  No more disappearing records.

Apparently there was something very strange in the way EFCore set up the database in the first place that caused the issue.  But I don't have any idea what it was.

Comment: Try to add this line to your constructor inside your `WrapperContext` class : `Database.SetInitializer<WrapperContext>(null);`

Comment: @MarkC., I get the error 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SetInitializer' and no extendion method ... could be found.  I tried adding a reference to System.Data.Entity but apparently this is incompatible with .NET Core

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks - it was a shot in the dark

Comment: Are you sure there is data and then this method deletes the data? The reason I ask is because I answered a similar question some time ago and the database that the context was creating was not the same one the OP was looking at.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, yes.  I am watching it in SqliteManager and refresh while stepping through the code and at one point the data is there and at the next step it is gone.

Comment: How did you get the data in there? If you insert some data after the context has created the db, will it still delete those records?

Comment: Apparently.  I am running the sqlite3 executable and reading an SQL file that inserts the record.  Once that is done I can see the record in the DB.

Comment: Oh, I misread you question.  I don't know if it will do this after programmatically inserting data.  I will try that now.

Answer (score 3):

What is likely happening is that you are using CodeFirst /w EF, but taking a DB first approach when it comes to testing your new code. EF tracks schema changes within the database and my guess is that by you creating the table ahead of time it does not know that the schema is vetted, so it drops and recreates it on context start-up.

The fix here should be to create a "stub" test that populates a test record one time using your EF model. From there you should have a table that EF recognizes against that context and accepts. From there you can create test records in whatever editor for testing purposes.

SQLite has several limitations when it comes to schema migration that you probably will want to consider as well. (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations)

You might be better off setting up DB first, telling EF how to map to an existing SQLite schema rather than trying to use Code-First as migration is pretty limited for that DB engine.

Comment: How do you know the OP is taking the DB first approach?

Comment: Agreed. This seems like more of a guess than an answer

Comment: @StevePy, I'm not sure what you mean by taking a DB-first approach to testing.  I am trying to do code-first with EF, though.  I am simply following along with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite.  It seemed to work on another project but here it isn't working.  I am not concerned with migrations so much, though it could be an issue.  I am just trying to simplify the codebase via EF.  What is necessary to do DB first on a .NET-Core project?

Comment: He's trying to add records to an existing schema before instantiating his context. The behaviour EF is taking points to that the schema existing prior to the EF context setting it up. The wildcard here is EF Core which has all kinds of surprises in store as a relatively immature platform. My point is to try using the context to set up the schema and insert that row. From there it may recognize the schema and behave as "Create if Not Exists" provided that is still the default behavior in Core.

Comment: @melston: Try populating your test record with the context, typically I'll use a  NUnit test as a simple integration test to exercise my initial domain. (checking the schema out) From that you can try creating records in the database directly and assert whether these records continue to get purged.

Comment: @StevePy, what method should I override to do this population?

Comment: @melston: no override. If you're not familiar with NUnit and tests then try adding a simple one-off method that: a) create an instance of your WrappedContext b) create a WrappedFunction with the test data you want,  c) adds it  to the Context's Functions DbSet, and c) calls SaveChanges on the Context. After that, remove the stub method and verify your table is populated. Edit the table contents to add another row and run your existing code to determine whether it is still purging the table.

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood your meaning.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: And, for some reason, I am unable to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore as a reference to a unit test project.  I don't get any errors on restore but it won't build saying I need to add a reference - even though it is there in the .csproj file.

Comment: .Net runtime version mismatch in the test project? I haven't used NUnit /w Core. Worst case a simple stub method can at least confirm/eliminate whether this is EF's migration. My reading points at that migration shouldn't be happening automatically with EF core, but typically with emerging MS tech, the documentation tends to get stale pretty quick as they roll out updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147199/discussion-between-melston-and-steve-py).